# Fabric plugin cannot login via Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, twitter-fabric

I am using Android Studio 1.5, Fabric Plugin 2.3.1. What possible reasons would Fabric not allow me to login?

The whole process is completely knackered. Any Fabric link I visit including the [organization settings](https://fabric.io/settings/organizations) link located [here](https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/integration.html) directs me to the on-boarding link where all I can do is view instructions on how to download the plugin. I have installed the plugin, login and I see the list of Fabric components for about 2 seconds before it brings me back to the login screen with no message at all.

The credentials are fine (incorrect credentials give me an orange message saying so). I have tried it with 3 different accounts.

So now I am in a situation where I have 3 accounts, all of which only allow me to view instructions on how to download the plugin, and the plugin will not let me get further than the login screen. I could do this manually but cannot access the organization settings screen either. Any ideas?

EDIT: [This](https://twittercommunity.com/t/unable-to-login-in-fabric-plugin-in-android-studio/28511) is the closest similar issue I could find on their forums but it relates to a Mac (I'm on Windows 10, Java version jdk1.7.0_79)

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it for me was adding the authKey to the application block in the main manifest.

**NOTE: at the time of this issue, I am using Android Studio 2.0 Beta 6.  We believe that there might be an issue with the Fabric plugin and this version.**

To see what's happening to the Fabric plugin, I had to open the Console app and view the logs in realtime.  Sure enough, it showed that was authenticated with my credentials, AND it passed back the reason I was being sent right back to the login:  Missing authkey in the application block.

So I copied an authkey node from a previous project and added it to the manifest and bingo - it took me to the screen to install Crashlytics.

The thing is, I could have sworn that the Plugin was supposed to GIVE me the authkey after it installed Crashlytics, so I was a bit puzzled as to why this worked.  But it did.

Again, this is with Android Studio 2.0 Beta6 so it might be only related to that.  **But using the Console to diagnose the issue with the Fabric Plugin is the take away here.**

Answer (score -1):

Download the fabric plugin for android studio via jetbrains.com using your prefered browser(i.e mozilla,chrome etc).
 after your file get downloaded(not via andriod studio), open your AndroiStudio, goto --file>>settings>>plugin>>install plugin from disk, give the .jar file which you have downloaded, then restart studio